# How to programmatically populate FileEntity

Tags: 8, entities, files

I have a `file entity` with some custom fields, for example a date field.
How can I programmatically set the field values?

If I, for example, set date-field value with a `DrupalDateTime` object, I get an error on saving the entity.

```
$entity->set('field_myname', $drupalDateTimeObject);
$entity->save();

SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'field_myname_value'
```

So I assume there needs to be a transition between the DateTime object and the actual field value.
How can this transition be done dynamic, if the field types are dynamic?